# ActionBarSherlock requesting search

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I`m trying to request search from ActionBarSherlock.

My class extends SherlockListActivity.

This is how I`m adding Menu button to the ActionBar:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add("Save")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM |
                MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
        return true;
    }
```

The problem is that I am unable to invoke it by id:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId())  {
            case ?????: {
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

How people usually solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inflate you menu from an XML menu file you will set an id which you can then use in your `onOptionsItemSelected` method. Like this:

XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" android:title="@string/search"/>
</menu>
```

Fragment

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_search:
            onSearchRequested();

            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: case R.id.menu_search: - this cannot be found by compiller, if I do it this way...

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Refresh").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_refresh).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Search").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case 1:
                ...
                break;
            case 2:
                ...
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```